# FAILED (failures=1) Destroying test database for alias 'default' Is it ok?

Tags: python, django

I wrote test code,and run the file.
I wrote this code

```
from django.test import TestCase
from app.models import User

# Create your tests here.
class UserModelTests(TestCase):
    def test_is_empty(self):
        saved_db = list(User.objects.values()[:2])
        expected = [{'name': Tom,'user_id': 1,'nationarity': America, 'dormitory':'A', 'group': 3,'name': Bob,'user_id': 2,'nationarity': China, 'dormitory':'B', 'group': 4}]
        self.assertEqual(expected, saved_db)
```

so the result is

```
System check identified 60 issues (0 silenced).
F
======================================================================
FAIL: test_is_empty (app.tests.UserModelTests)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/app/tests.py", line 12, in test_is_empty
    self.assertEqual(expected, saved_db)
AssertionError: Lists differ: [{'name': 1, 'fixed_constructi[4938 chars]: 0}] != []

First list contains 1 additional elements.
First extra element 0:
{'name': Tom,'user_id': 1,'nationarity': America, 'dormitory':'A', 'group': 3,'name': Bob,'user_id': 2,'nationarity': China, 'dormitory':'B', 'group': 4}
Diff is 5605 characters long. Set self.maxDiff to None to see it.

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.013s

FAILED (failures=1)
Destroying test database for alias 'default'...
```

I cannot understand this code is ok or not.When I print out saved_db several times,the order of the list is changed each time.So I doubt I can compare list of expected& saved_db correctory.Is it ok?Should I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are comparing a list of two dicts with a list with one dict.

```
expected = [
    {'name': Tom
     'user_id': 1
     'nationarity': America,
     'dormitory':'A',
     'group': 3,
    # Missing closure for dict: }, list sep and opener:
    #  }, {
     'name': Bob,
     'user_id': 2, ...
    }
]
```

This is why indenting and long line chopping is so important.

After fixing the dictionaries in the list, it is probably better to do the testcode like this and avoid dictionary ordering problems:

```
for index, item in enumerate(expected):
    self.assertDictEqual(item, saved_db[index])
```

This however, assumes a stable sorting order in the Model.

The djangonic way of doing it would be:

```
class UserModelTests(TestCase):
    def test_is_empty(self):
        queryset = User.objects.order_by('user_id').values()[:2]
        expected = [
            {'name': 'Tom', 'user_id': 1, 'nationarity': 'America', 'dormitory': 'A', 'group': 3},
            {'name': 'Bob', 'user_id': 2, 'nationarity': 'China', 'dormitory': 'B', 'group': 4}
        ]
        for idx, item in enumerate(expected):
            self.assertDictEqual(item, queryset[idx])
```

As pointed out by @rafaimp, if you do not have [data migrations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/migrations/#data-migrations) that have inserted the `User` objects then you should assume your database is empty. The way to add data is either by using [fixtures](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/testing/tools/#fixture-loading) or fill the [`setUpTestData`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.TestCase.setUpTestData) method.

Comment: thx ur answer!!Yes,it is right.Should I use Orderdict?If i do not use Orderdict,maybe the order of dictionary is changed each run time, right?

Comment: No, your problem is not with the dictionary, it's with the list: Expected has **one** dictionary in the list. It should have **two** and I've shown above where you should fix it.

Comment: @Melvyn you're missing the point here; for tests a new, empty database is created (and restored to initial state for each test case class) so your `queryset` will always be an empty list (unless you fill the DB with some data, either in the test method or in `setUp()`; see [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/testing/overview/#the-test-database) and [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/testing/tools/#transactiontestcase)

Comment: @rafaimp Ah true. Was wondering why the method is called is_empty(). Still, the test can still succeed if [data migrations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/migrations/#data-migrations) have been applied. `fixtures` attribute or `setUp()` isn't the only way to get data in the test database. But with correct data the test would fail because of the list/dict problem. Integrating your comment.

Comment: @Melvyn I wrote ur code, but No migration error happens because of ur writing about no fixtures&setUp() .I wanna add fixtures&setUp()  to my codes, but I cannot understand how to do it.How should I write it?

Comment: @rafalmp I wrote Melvyn's code, but No migration error happens because of ur writing about no fixtures&setUp() .I wanna add fixtures&setUp() to my codes, but I cannot understand how to do it.How should I write it?